# Display multiple images using for loop - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to display 89 images, and each image is stored as numpy array with shape of [89, 14*79]

I reshaped each data using reshape [79,14], and the entire images have to be displayed.

Since I want to show 5 images in each row, I would have 18 rows in total.

My code is here below

```
for i in range(89):
    pixels=cp_cfd[i,:].reshape(79, 14)
    plt.subplot(1,5,i+1)
    plt.imshow(pixels, cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
    plt.title('#'+str(i+1))
plt.show()
```

With `plt.subplot(1,5,i+1)` I got an error. and I have only five images in the first row.

```
ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 5, not 6
```

I know that I should use `plt.subplot(18,5,i+1)` instead of `plt.subplot(1,5,i+1)` for entire images, but when I use `plt.subplot(18,5,i+1)`, the size of images become too small. 
I would like to display entire 89 images, but with the size of them when I use `plt.subplot(1,5,i+1)`

Please help me..

Comment: how do you expect to display `89` images if you want to create only one row ?

Comment: @furas I can have multiple rows but as `nrow` element in `plt.subplot(nrow, , )` increases, the size of image decreases by dividing that number..

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I solved my own question though.

```
cfd_last = x_cfd.shape[0]

for i in range(18): # number of rows of plot
    for j in range(5):

        if i*5+j == cfd_last:
            break

        pixels=cp_cfd[i*5+j,:].reshape(79, 14)
        plt.subplot(1,5,j+1)
        plt.imshow(pixels, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
        plt.title('#'+str(i*5+j+1))


    plt.show()
```